# cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'position') Minecraft mineflayer

Tags: node.js, path-finding, goal-tracking, mineflayer

I'm programming a Minecraft bot to follow me, I used this code in lot of projects before 8 months and it worked. But now I have a problem that NodeJS is saying he cannot read 'position'.
Code :

```
const mineflayer = require("mineflayer")
const { pathfinder, goals, Movements } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder')
const GoalFollow = goals.GoalFollow

const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 57470,
    version: "1.16.5",
    username: "BotWG"
})
bot.loadPlugin(pathfinder)

function followPlayer() {
    bot.chat("I've spawned")
    const playerFilter = entity => entity.type === "player"
    const player = bot.nearestEntity(playerFilter)
    if(!player) return
    const playerTF = bot.players[player]
    const mcData = require("minecraft-data")(bot.version)
    const mcMovements = new Movements(bot, mcData)
    bot.pathfinder.setMovements(mcMovements)

    const goal = new GoalFollow(playerTF, 1)
    bot.pathfinder.setGoal(goal, true)
}

bot.on("spawn", followPlayer)
```

I've done this code before 8 months ago and it worked. I've installed all the needed packages and when I active the bot he'll join to my world and write "I've joined" then he'll leave and show me this error:

C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\wg bot\node_modules\mineflayer-pathfinder\lib\goals.js:329                                           this.x = Math.floor(entity.position.x)                                                                                                             ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'position')                                                         at new GoalFollow (C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\wg bot\node_modules\mineflayer-pathfinder\lib\goals.js:329:32)                at EventEmitter.followPlayer (C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\wg bot\index.js:24:18)                                             at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:525:35)                                                                               at Client. (C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\wg bot\node_modules\mineflayer\lib\plugins\health.js:13:11)               at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)                                                                              at Client.emit (node:events:525:35)                                                                                     at emitPacket (C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\wg bot\node_modules\minecraft-protocol\src\client.js:83:12)                       at FullPacketParser. (C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\wg bot\node_modules\minecraft-protocol\src\client.js:106:9)     at FullPacketParser.emit (node:events:513:28)                                                                           at addChunk (C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\wg bot\node_modules\protodef\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:279:12)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Node.js v18.16.0